# Unauthorized access error while building docker file on windows

Tags: java, docker, webserver

I have started learning docker on windows 10. I have made following docker file

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD D:\project\test-service\target\test-service-1.0.war test-service.war
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","test-service.war"]
```

to build I am running the command

```
docker build -f <filename> -t <session name> .
```

while running I am getting error Unauthorized access. I have logged in into docker service from UI.

I have also tried command "docker login" still it is saying invalid user id password.
Please suggest how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same issue it was resolved by the below method:

use command

```
docker login
```

it will ask you to enter your user id and password
your email is not your user id so login to https://hub.docker.com/ you will see your user id in the top right corner

use that user id and your password to login.